# How to access the fields of account.account model from the account.invoice model in a xml Qweb view?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9

I 'm doing a report on the account.account model but not access the fields of account.invoice model :
My view xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<t t-name="account.reporte_balance">
    <t t-call="report.internal_layout" style="font-size:8px;">
        <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
        <div class="page">
            <div class="oe_structure"/>
                <div class="row"  style="font-size:8px;">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">.....
```

To access the fields of another model that should write the following. But not getting the account.account specifically model.

```
**<tr t-foreach="HERE WRITE THE ACCOUNT.ACCOUNT MODEL REL" t-as="o">**
     <td class="text-center">
          <span t-field="o.code"/>
     </td>......
```

I appreciate any help . Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 1):

if *invoices* is a list of invoices you can do this:

```
<tr t-foreach="invoices" t-as="inv">**
    <td class="text-center">
        <span t-field="inv.account_id.name"/>
    </td>
</tr>
```

that said, i don't understand what *o.* is in your code...

Comment: Odoo shows me the following error:
QWebException : need more than 1 value to unpack


What does this mean?

Comment: usually is involved a tuple. this seems not related to this very question, thus you should create a new question showing your code and the exception trace